# How to make requests from java-based apps to geoserver (or any other kind)?

Tags: spring, gis, microservices, openlayers, geoserver

I'm designing a GIS 3D system to be run inside a cloud environment (where other systems run and intercommunicate between each other). I'm thinking about using openlayers + cesium.js, a custom app and geoserver.

Due to I don't know if geoserver will fit my requirements in the future, I'm thinking about making my custom app (spring boot based) as a facade of geoserver. This way, I could switch geoserver without breaking the systems, authenticate users like the other system, split business requirements, etc.

I've been reading about RestTemplate to make calls from my application to geoserver, but i'm not sure if it can handle other kind of request (as the ones the frontend would need).

- Could you give me any hints on this?
- Do you think my approach is in the good direction?
- Do you know any other approach or tool to do those calls?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GeoServer](https://geoserver.org) only uses REST to handle administrative tasks. You should look at using [OGC standards](http://www.opengeospatial.org/) like [WMS](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wms) and [WFS](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wfs) to talk to your map service then you can switch to any conforming server at a later date.